# How to read exact numbers as displayed in excel using Pandas.read_excel or xlwrings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I am new in Python programming, and I am having an issue regarding to Pandas.
I've searched for similar questions using different keywords but unfortunately didn't find the right answer.

What I intended to achieve is simply read data from excel but can keep the original accuracy from Excel.

The data is Excel is like this:

[image: excel data]

I tried two ways of reading excel.
One:

```py
#using pandas
import pandas as pd
df_input=pd.read_excel(excel_path,sheet_name,dtype={'Column E':str}
```

Two:

```py
#using xlwings
df_input=wb.sheets[excel_sheeet_name].used_range.options(pd.DataFrame,index=False).value
```

The result after running different code looks like this:

[image: code result]

I understand this is probably because of float? But How can I get '2400.0144' instead of '2400.0143999999996'?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
import pandas as pd
df_input=pd.read_excel(excel_path,sheet_name,dtype={'Column E':str}
```

You are mentioning 'Column E' as a **str**. But I see that you are reading from a float, change it to `{'Column E':float}`. I hope that this fixes it.

You can also use the **round** function in python to round off to specific digits if the above doesn't fix the issue: [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/round)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I changed it to {'Column E':float} but still the same result. The round solution cannot solve the problem either because the number is dynamic thus the digits of decimals is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those Excel annomalies where the value of the floating point calculation is not accurate, in your case calculated as '2400.0143999999996' instead of 2400.0144.

Therefore the 'value' saved by Excel for the formula calulation with the values currently in the sheet is '2400.0143999999996' and when reading the cell as a string in pandas that's the value returned.
The answer from Rajat Shenoi however is valid and should display the number correctly as a float i.e. as '2400.0144'. Although it does also means that all the numbers in that column will then display as floats (with 4 decimal places being that is the largest number of decimal places of all the numbers) rather than as strings which may be your preferred view.

Try the following to see if it will do what you want. This example uses the 4 column 5 row example sheet you have provided. For comparison I'm adding an extra column to this Excel Sheet however you can obviously make the change to the existing column L, 'Column E' if you don't want to add the extra column.
I have also changed the values in cells 'J3' and 'J4' to give values with 2 and 3 decimal places in the formulas.
In column M (insert a new column if necessary), give it the header 'Rounded E' then enter the formula =ROUND(L2,6). Setting the rounding with a max of 6 decimal places. Copy this formula down the column for the rest of the populated rows.
Cell 'M2' should now have a value of '2400.0144' (assuming the Excel number format is not otherwise modifying the display)
Excel Sheet should now look like this
[image: Excel Sheet change]


Change the 'using pandas section' of your code to the following;

```
### using pandas
df_input = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name, dtype={'Column E': float, 'Rounded E': str})
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
print(df_input)
```

Since the value for cell M2 stored by Excel would be '2400.0144' that is the value you should see in pandas under the 'Rounded E' column and the rest of the column also being strings will show with only the necessary number of decimal placings.
Column L 'Column E' is formatted to float with 5 decimals places so all numbers will pad to 5 decimal places . The number of decimal places is set using **{:.5f}** in the line

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
```

All values should have only the number of places specified in the format setting.

The last two columns would display as below, the 'Rounded E' column showing only the necessary number of decimal places.

```
  Column E  Rounded E
2400.01440  2400.0144
3600.04800   3600.048
3000.06000    3000.06
3600.00000       3600
3120.00000       3120
```